# HTTPS WSDL ANDROID wsimport

Tags: java, https, wsdl

Можно ли сгенерить java классы с wsimport по wsdl, потом все это дело скормить android? может кто даст пример работы данной связки?

Answer (score 1):

Для генерации классов вы можете использовать этот сайт. Он сгенирирует код за вас.
http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/Home.aspx

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.